# Start arduino serial communication

Tags: php, linux, arduino

I have set up an arduino sketch that reads commands on the serial line and turns on or off a number of relays. This works just like expected when I test it from the IDE. What I want to do is to be able to control it from a web interface, so I have made a php-script in which the basis part is

```
$dev='/dev/ttyACM0';
exec("/bin/stty -F $dev 9600" );
$fp=fopen($dev,"c+");
if(!$fp) die("Can't open device $dev");
// Set blocking mode for writing
stream_set_blocking($fp,1);
for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++){
   $_GET[$i]=trim($_GET[$i]);
   if($_GET[$i]=='ON'){
       $cmd="H${i}_";
   }
   if($_GET[$i]=='OFF'){
       $cmd="L${i}_";
   }
   fwrite($fp,$cmd);
}
```

(sending H1_ turns on relay 1, L1_ turns it of and so on)

This also work fine, If I just have done some communication in the IDE. If I restart my work station (running debian linux), the php script will not work (no error message, just nothing happening) until I have "touched" the arduino board (a uno) through the IDE. The initialisation of the sketch is just

```
int R1 = 4; // relay 1 - 4
int R2 = 5;
int R3 = 6;
int R4 = 7;

void setup() 
{ // Setting the relay pins for output
    pinMode(R1, OUTPUT);     
    pinMode(R2, OUTPUT);     
    pinMode(R3, OUTPUT);     
    pinMode(R4, OUTPUT);     
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
```

As I said, this works fine, it just needs some extra initialisation, but where and how?